# Fetching collections which are available only in the shopify store's menu via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

Need to fetch the collections available only in the shopify store's menu through API. Menu collections are subset of published collections. All the published collections will not be shown in the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve this.

There is no API at the moment that can target the Menu Navigations.

You can get the published collections but there is no way to know which are in a navigation.

Here is a similar question asked in their community: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Navigation-API-Endpoint/td-p/465701